# How to change visibility on div multiple times with javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have a popup in my app:

```
<div id="modal"></div>

let modal = document.getElementById('modal')
modal.innerHTML = `
            <button class="close-button" onclick="close_modal()">Close</button>
        `

#modal{
        width: 30em;
        height: 24em;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

When I click certain button function is triggered which has modal.classList.add('open-modal') in it.

```
.open-modal{
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
```

`close_modal` function is:

```
function close_modal(){
        modal.classList.add('close-modal')
    }
```

CSS:

```
.close-modal{
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
```

It works just fine once(i can open and close popup but when I try to open it second time it doesn't. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding a new class, you must remove the previous class from the element's classlist. So the modal won't seem to work anymore after having both classes at the same time.

for ex.

```js
function changeVisibility(modal) {
 if(modal.classList.contains('open-modal')) {
   modal.classList.remove('open-modal');
   modal.classlist.add('close-modal');
 } else {
    modal.classList.remove('close-modal');
    modal.classList.add('open-modal')
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to do modals, you should use HTML's [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element (Also see [`HTMLDialogElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement)). MDN has a tutorial on it.